# What is the funny looking thing attached to my new mazda3 key fob?

Tags: mazda, key, keyless-entry, mazda-3, fob

I got my new 2016 mazda3 today from the dealer and tossed the second key fob right in my backpack without taking a look.

Then I found there was this weird looking thing attached to it. It has "**iButton.com**" engraved on it.

- What is it?
- What does it do to my car?

[image: weird looking key fob]

Comment: Did you think to ask the dealer-salesman? Its a pretty poor car salesman that does not go over all the features of the car before letting you drive away.

Comment: I can find no documentation on it being used by Mazda....https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/comms/ibutton.html

Comment: It could be used for other reasons as stated in the link I provided, it looks suspicious and may be something that particular dealership is doing like data tracking you. If the car operates without it I would remove it from the keychain until you find an honest answer on what Exactly it is being used for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a dealer ID tag. The salesman and managers use it to check keys in and out. They should have taken it off of the key before they handed it to you. If you don't want it, just take it off and throw it away (if the dealership sucked) or take it off and return it if you feel extra nice.

EDIT: [Here is the webpage for them.](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/digital/memory-products/DS1990R-F3.html) Their claim is *inventory control*, which is what is happening with the key.

Comment: Thanks @Paulster2! My friend's blood sugar was a little low when we were checking out the vehicle. So we got the first set of key and drove to a restaurant before he gave us the second set. He was being extra nice. I guess that's when things were messed up. So one question, does he need the ID tag, or he might have some spares?

Comment: Every set of keys in the dealership should have one of these tags. They don't need it as they'll have spares, but if you are feeling nice and are in the neighborhood, I'm sure they'd appreciate the return. If the salesman was especially good to you, you may want to return it anyway. I wouldn't know for sure, but they may get in trouble and have to pay for it.